# Jmeter Configuration

Tags: performance, jmeter, stress-test

I need help to configure Jmeter.
Can anybody help with this following error (if loop count is not -1 or forever, duration will be min(duration, loop count*iteration duration)
Note that system time is not appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get what you want at all? Can you please ask the question in a clear way with more details. What are you trying to do exactly? What have you tried?